# How can I search for a specific JSON value in mongoDB via Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

Hello lets suppose that we had store this JSON

```
'{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}';
```

in a mongoDB database and this database after is connected with kafka.
How can i search for a value like `"New York"` in mongoDB via Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has no search functionality, only seek+scan.

If the data is in Mongo, you would query the collection, and this would be done outside of Kafka.

Comment: What do you mean this is a pub/sub system and i can't query for specific data? I confused, then how a company can have access for specific values in a database which connect with the kafka. Also for collection how will I ask the kafka,should i declare that an offset in kafka refers to a specific collection?

Comment: No pub/sub system that i know of has any query interface. You only publish new events or subscribe to old/new events (assuming old events are stored, like in kafka)... I dont understand your question... A SourceConnector reads an entire Mongo Collection, yes. A SinkConncetor will land all topic data into a single Collection as well

Comment: ok may i confused with orion context broker i will check it again. But a last question, If I want for example information for a person like above which it stored in mongoDB,can I fetch all latest the information about this person and after if I need only one value I have to filter the message?

Comment: I'm just really here to answer the Kafka questions, but that seems reasonable query in Mongo

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this out-of-the-box but it does look like the folks at https://batch.sh can make it happen - dunno about cost though.